# Hapi FHIR Strange behaviour of _sort

Tags: sorting, hl7-fhir, hapi

The parameter _sort in hapi fhir 4.2 shows a strange behaviour. While a query without any conditions like /Procedure returns all existing procedures, a sorted query like /Procedure?_sort=date returns only procedures having a date != null.

From a developers perspective one might say: Ok, I don't have a value to sort by, so I can't make an assertation, but practically this makes the _sort parameter completely useless for fields that can be null.

Why is a value of Null not treated as the least possible value for the field, like in sql or other ?

I got through the Hapi fhir changelog, but havn't found this issue mentioned ( for me, it is an issue )

I know that sort parameters are based on search parameters. Does anyone know whether there is a chance to change this behaviour by any option in the searchparameter ?
I guess No :-(

Cheers
Christian

Comment: I've tried this on the current public HAPI server (running 5.2.0-SNAPSHOT), and _sort does include the resources that do not have a value for the sort field. If you look at the changelog, there's mention of sorting and all kinds of things improved there. This might not have been mentioned as such, but has clearly been improved.

Comment: Its a known issue, but can be fixed. See James answer here https://groups.google.com/g/hapi-fhir/c/TmICVa9hKFI